# Have there been any efforts to release opossums as a biological control against ticks?

Tags: environment, pest-control

There's plenty of examples of people recognizing opossums as a great ally in controlling tick populations ([here's one example](https://www.caryinstitute.org/newsroom/use-wild-opossums-rid-your-property-ticks)). However, I can't find any examples of opossums being intentionally released or supported in areas specifically to control ticks.

Have there been any efforts documented that deliberately increase opossum populations to reduce tick infestations? If no, are there specific reasons why this has not been done? For the latter, there are of course examples of biological control gone wrong (e.g. [cane toads released in Australia](https://gen.uga.edu/documents/pest/Biological%20Control%20Gone%20Bad.pdf)), but that doesn't seem to deter all biological pest controls (e.g. [nematodes to control fungus gnats](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7448.html)).

Comment: I think you have given the answer yourself. Opossums can be agressive predators, intentional release in new area's is simply an extremely bad idea from a ecological point of view.

Comment: @RHA that's certainly a reason why no one would try this. I wanted to check if anyone has tried it or there's been any serious consideration of it. Maybe it's simply too crazy and no agency has given it serious thought.